# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Undeclared variable:

Tags: error-handling, fatal-error

I keep getting this error on my host, but not at local server.

> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Undeclared variable:

This is my code:

```
$cm="SELECT * FROM wpas_posts WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $page,$index_image";
$cm2=mysqli_query($dbs,$cm) or die(mysqli_error()); //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR COMES FROM
while($cm3 = mysqli_fetch_array($cm2))
```

I did try to update and hide the errors, but the same happens